# Is a follower-following table a many to many relationship?

Tags: python, django, database-design, django-models, orm

I have two models. One model is a Users table which contains fields like `id, username, email` and I have another table which is used to show a follower and following relationship.  The Following model is shown:

```
class Following(models.Model):
    target = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='followers', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    follower = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='targets', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} is followed by {}'.format(self.target, self.follower)
```

I have made this assuming that the relationship between Users and Following is a one to many relationship (One user can have many followers, and can follow many as well). Is this correct? Or should it be a many to many relationship. If so, why? I have seen many instances of this table schema being both many to many and one to many.

User Class:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username    = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    email       = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                       null=True) 
    active      = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff       = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin       = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: You need to provide more details about the needs of your specific application.  As it stands, I don't know if anyone can tell, based on the information here, whether "Users" and "Followers" are one-to-many or many-to-many.

Comment: @Brian I updated the question with the User class. I'm thinking User has a one to many relationship with the Followers table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using predicates **[px]** and constraints *[cx.y]*.

---

**[p1]** User (UserID) exists.

*[c1.1]* User is identified by UserID.

```
user {UserID}  -- p1
 KEY {UserID}  -- c1.1
```

---

**[p2]** Follower (FollowerID) follows author (AuthorID).

*[c2.1]* Follower is a user.

*[c2.2]* Author is a user.

*[c2.3]* For each follower, that follower may follow more than one author.

*[c2.4]* For each author, that author may be followed by more than one follower.

*[c2.5]* For each combination of author and follower, that combination of that author and that follower may occur at most once.

*[c2.6]* Authors may not follow themselves.

```
following {AuthorID, FollowerID} -- p2
      KEY {AuthorID, FollowerID} -- c2.5, c2.3, c2.4

FOREIGN KEY {FollowerID} REFERENCES user {UserID} -- c2.1
FOREIGN KEY {AuthorID}   REFERENCES user {UserID} -- c2.2

      CHECK AuthorID != FollowerID                -- c2.6
```

---

Bottom line, many-to-many. You can always tweak this to reflect your specific needs by focusing on conceptual/logical design expressed in natural language -- predicates and constraints.

Comment: Hmm I see, inside the table there's a many to many relationship. What benefit does it provide with fields having a many to many relationship?

Comment: @user2896120 it is simply a consequence of the logical model, see c2.3 and 2.4.

Comment: So is it more about logic than benefit?

Comment: @user2896120 well, yes -- "*relationship*" is a model speak (OO, ERD); logic is the essence here.